# type trait with enum as specialisation

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I would like to have a type trait that would be false for any parameter T except for the enum value `Http::Get`

```
template<typename T>
  struct isGet : public std::false_type{};

template<>
  struct isGet<Http::Get> : public std::true_type {};
```

However, it seems that the c++ compiler does not allow me to specialise a template class with an enum when the first is a typename.

If I instead do :

```
template<Http T>
  struct isGet : public std::false_type{};
```

it works!

Any reason why that is the case, and what are the workarounds to achieve what I want.

I basically want the compiler to return the type trait to false even when T is not of a enum type `Http`

Comment: change `template<typename T>` to `template<auto>` is enough

Comment: It makes very little sense to pass in a type or a value to a template. Why would you even want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typename` and `class` expect types. `Http::Get` is (presumably) not a type, but a value, like any other constant (`42`, `'A'`, `false` etc.). And you obviously cannot pass a value when a type is expected.

The solution would be different depending on your use cases. For example:

```
#include <type_traits>

enum class Http {
    Post,
    Get,
};

template <auto T>
struct isGet : public std::false_type {};

template <>
struct isGet<Http::Get> : public std::true_type {};
```